# How to make operator return reference to string element

Tags: c++, string

I've got my custom string class:

```
#include <string.h>

class String
{
    char * str;
    int n;
public:
    explicit String(const char* s)
    {
        n = strlen(s);
        str = new char[n + 1];
        strcpy(str, s);
        printf("Class constructor\n");
    }
    ~String() { delete[] str; printf("Class destructor\n"); };
    const char& operator [] (int i) const
    {
        return (i >= 0 && i < n) ? this->str[i] : 0;
    }
}
```

I have already implement indexing operator that returns `const char`, but i want to have an indexing operator, that returns reference to string element.I know it can be done using `friend`, but my attemps to write it were unsuccessful.

Can you give me some suggestions on how my problem can be solved?

Comment: Could you please add more details to your questions? Why would you want to return a reference to the string (I guess it's `char*`) for an indexing operator?

Comment: I don't quite understand, isn't what you want to do simply `char& operator [] (int i) { return str[i]; }` ?  (you need to add bound checking and exception of course...)

Comment: I am assuming you are writing `String` for educational purposes, and don't intend to use it in real code. Using `std::string` is much less work, and interoperates with more existing code.

Comment: @AdrianShum But i have my str in private, won't it affect your example? E.g i have String s("Hello world");s[0] will be 'H', and i want ++s[0] to be next element 'e', not 'I' in ASCII order

Comment: @lapalap it seems what you are trying to do is something like an iterator. A bit weird to use `[]` though but it should be fine to return an iterator with `[]` operator, and with a `char` casting operator ?  But the whole thing is strange... people expect `s[0]` gives you a `char`, of course they expect `++` a `s[0]` to be incrementing the char instead

Comment: @lapalap: You can't affect the way C++ is parsed. `++s[0]` is `++(s[0])`. Since you return a `char`, the `++` operator on that character. That's the built-in `operator++`, not something you can define. You'll need another syntax. That said, the canonical implementation of this idea  would be `const char* String::begin() const { return str; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view. You can either use it, or define for yourself a similar analog to std::string and your String class.

Then you would have

```
string_view operator[] (size_t i) const
{
    if(i >= n) { return string_view(nullptr, 0); }
    return string_view(str[i], n - i);
}
```

Note that you *don't* want to use your `String` class for this, as it owns and copies the data. Instead you want a class with no ownership, but similar methods.